# Understanding how this works

Tags: c++, binary, ascii

I'm currently learning C++ at my school and we got a assignment to translate binary to ASCII.

Me and my friend found this code here on this site.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
  std::ofstream fout("ASCII.txt");
  std::ifstream fin("Binary.txt");
  char ic;
  std::bitset<8> oc;
  int i = 8;

  while (fin >> ic) 
  {
    oc[--i] = ic - '0';

    if (0 == i) 
    {
      fout << static_cast<char>(oc.to_ulong());
      i = 8; 
    } 
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Could someone with a bit of spare-time explain more in detail what this means?
We do understand "fstream" and how he reads the files.
But bitsets is a little blurry, and we can't find any GOODGOOD tutorial on how it works, also what happens during the -for and -while loops.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're a beginner, `std::bitset` will probably instantly fail the assignment for you. You have learned everything you need to know in class; use what you've learned. The purpose of assignments is not to produce a particular correct output, it's to practice problem solving with a set of given tools so you learn about them.

Comment: And if you want to learn about bitsets then this can be a good article to start with. But don't stop here, keep exploring and practicing. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-bitset-and-its-application/

Comment: @molbdnilo We were told to find a function, and I thought i'd be interesting to learn about bitsets. But I understand what you mean, thank you.

Comment: @Sisir Thank you. :)

Comment: Please understand that the ASCII part of this is the _input_. Actually, not ASCII itself necessarily but the "execution character set" the compiler translates '0' to. The input is text; The output is what is often called "binary" (opaque data). (It could very well be that the output is intended to be interpreted as text with the ASCII character encoding, too, but that has nothing to do with your progaram.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code opens two files:

ASCII.txt is opened for writing via the `ofstream` class instance, `fout`

Binary.txt is opened for reading via the `ifstream` class instance, `fin`

`bitset` is simply an array of bits.  `oc` is a bitset of 8 bits, effectively 1 byte.

The while loop proceeds like this:

- `fin >> ic`: read a character from `fin` (Binary.txt) and copy into `ic` (presumably this is either a `'0'` or `'1'` char.
- `ic - '0'`: Convert the ascii char read above into `ic` directly into a number `0` or `1` by subtracting from the ascii value of the character `'0'`.
- `oc[--i] =` decrement `i` and then pack the `0` or `1` bit into the bitset at position `i`
- `fout << static_cast<char>(oc.to_ulong());`: Every 8th iteration through the loop, a the bitset is now full and is a complete byte. Convert it back to an integer, cast to "char" and write the character back to `fout` (ASCII.txt). There's a lot going on in this statement.
- the loop continues until there are no more bytes to read from `fin` (Binary.txt)

Comment: Thanks man, really useful information! Have a great day!